# react native infinite scrolling with performance optimization both horizontally and vertically

Tags: react-native

I need a ListView or Table or any other custom component that can have **infinite scrolling in both horizontal and vertical directions**. For example, **10,000 rows and 10,000 columns**. We have the **react-native's FlatList** component but it can be **used for either vertical or horizontal** but not for both. If the data is finite, we can go with implementing a vertical scrollView inside a horizontal scrollView or vice-versa. But as we are looking for infinite scrolling, we are not able to use scrollView as it tries to load the entire content when the app is opened and the memory consumption is very huge so that the app automatically crashes. Does anyone have any idea if there are any third party libraries that can ***scroll both vertically and horizontally and also can look after the performance***? Actually, is that possible to build such a component on our own in react-native? If so, please tell me if you have any ideas.

Comment: Even I am facing a similar issue tried many ways but I couldn't find a solution.